# LMM: fixed effect significant in complex model, but not in reduced model

Tags: r, multiple-regression, mixed-model

I constructed two models with `lme4::lmer`:

`decomposition ~ trait1 + trait2 + trait3 + (1|pair)`

all trait effects are highly significant

yet when I run this simplified model:

`decomposition ~ trait1 + trait2 + (1|pair)`

the effect of `trait1` is not significant, `trait2` is significant.

How is this possible and what can I conclude about the effect of `trait1`?
I have 50 observations, if that matters.
Can this be due to model assumptions that are not met? I visually checked for homoscedasticity and did a formal test for normality of residuals, which appear to be fine though.

Comment: FWIW this question is not at all specific to mixed models.  The phenomenon is most likely still there even if you drop the random effect (i.e. use `lm()` to do a regular linear model).  I believe trait3 is a *confounder*, i.e. a variable that if not controlled for obscures the effect of trait1. I bet there are lots of questions on this site that deal with variants of this question, but I'm not quite sure how to search for them.

Comment: @BenBolker is likely correct. Read up on multicollinearity.

Comment: I believe that multicollinearity would typically work in the opposite direction (i.e. traits would be non-significant in the full model but become significant in the reduced model?)  I may not have used the "confounder" terminology correctly ...

Answer (score 3):

This looks like you have a problem with *multicollinearity*: trait1 and trait3 are correlated.

You can imagine creating such a scenario like so:

- Find a covariate (we'll call it `trait.unseen`) that is useful for predicting the response;
- Create a variable that is just noise (`trait1 <- rnorm()`);
- Create a second variable that is the combination of these: `trait3 <- trait1 + trait.unseen`.

Then `trait3` is a noisy estimate of a useful variable and `trait1` is used to eliminate the noise in `trait3`. Without `trait3`, `trait1` is not useful. Thus a model with `trait1` and `trait3` will show both are significant while a model with only `trait1` will show it as not significant.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that `trait3` could make `trait1` appear significant in that way. It seems counterintuitive that just noise can eliminate noise in `trait3`.

Comment: It has to be the same or highly correlated noise, but yes it can happen.